# dropping water from a height and plotting the spread

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-modeling

Im working on building a basic model which simulates the spread of water when dropped from a firefighting helicopter. To make a start I just want to plot the spread of water dropped from a fixed point.

I decided to treat the volume of water as discrete particles that fall from a height h, and at an angle $\Theta$ which is normally distributed around an estimated mean (not sure yet what to set mean to yet, 90 degrees? since its dropping from a fixed point). Ive coded this scenario in R:
The first plot is what my code produces
The second plot is what I am trying to achieve (think about how water disperses if you drop it on the ground)
can someone help me figure out how to plot the second graph with each data points x, y coordinate as a function of $\theta$. Thankyou in advance.

[image]

[image: This is the output of my code][image: This is what i am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $\sin$ is obviously wrong, because $|\sin x|\le 1$ for all $x$, so the absolute value of the result will never be less than `drop_ht`. If you draw the triangle, you will see that

`x_coord1 <- drop_ht * tan(drop_angx)`
`y_coord1 <- drop_ht * tan(drop_angy)`

is the true result of your model.

But this shows you that your model is flawed $-$ if the `rnorm` function is a normal distribution, then your model blows up when `drop_angx` or `drop_angy` is close to $90^\circ$. I would be more inclined to treat `x_coord` and `y_coord` as being normally distributed, with a standard deviation that depends on `drop_ht` somehow.

Comment: Thankyou! I do like your idea of normally distribuing the x, y coordinates with the stddev dependent on drop_ht... I will try doing something like that